# Codesys how to share local library repository

Tags: repository, shared-libraries, codesys, codesynthesis

we are developing some private libraries and are wondering how do we get them shared between different users of the team?
Same as a git repository (I guess) but do we need to have them stored in Codesys store as a private repository or we can have them stored on our local server and different user to sync to that backend?
Default settings for the Managed Libraries are in the local drive C:/ProgramData, which works for a single user but not very well where a team need to access the library.

Comment: If you want something more automatic, probably either use Subversion (requires Pro version if I remember correctly), or develop something inhouse using the Python ScriptEngine API (for example, have a central server where you can upload updated library files, and have a Python script on every machine that either runs automatically, or by users choice, that checks for new files on the server, downloads it and runs codesys to install the library). And finally, if none of the above are possible for you or team is small, just pass and install the library manually ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yes, I do understand, the problem is with tracking the updates, as if I pass on the library and install it manually, then new updates/bug fixes will need to be handled manually as well. While in my library repository, when I install to the library repository this will be tracked and updated on all projects using the library.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if it's your system or another's. If you install an updated library with the same version, it will be updated in all projects on that system (after the next build/compile). If the update also changed the version of the library (for example 1.0.0.0 -> 1.0.0.1), then the developer on that system has to manually change the version in the Library Manager for every project they want to use the new library.

Comment: we also have a problem with the compiled-library when we install the library the compiled-library this still shows the source code. Is this any settings we need to change in the project? Also we would like to protect the library project with a password, while the compiled-library should be loaded without password, is this possible at all?

Comment: The source code appears if codesys can find the project with source in the library repository. Compiled Libraries do not come with that source, however if you previously had installed the library normally (not compiled) and then installed the same library as compiled, then codesys would find the source since it doesn't remove the previous install. Try uninstalling the library before reinstalling the compiled library. If you set a password it should only protect the source project, afaik.